# What happens when using clientVersionStalenessDays() if more updates are available?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-update, google-play-core

I'm looking into supporting in app updates, and wanted to use the google core library for handling this. While doing this a question came up regarding the clientVersionStalenessDays() function. (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateInfo.html#clientVersionStalenessDays())

Say a user is running version 1 of an app, then i create a new update with version 2 which then is published to the play store. After 2 days i would expect the function to return 2 on the user device. If a new version 3 then was published on day 5 and the same function was run again would it return 5 or 0 since a new version was released the same day?

Related to:
[Internal app update: clientVersionStalenessDays() returning null when testing with internal app sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63134939/internal-app-update-clientversionstalenessdays-returning-null-when-testing-wi/71305604#71305604)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getClientVersionStalenessDays` returns the number of days that the Google Play Store app on the user's device has known about an available update. Since version 2 is an update that the PlayStore knows about, the method would return the number of days since version 2 is available.